# Vuejs 2 Sending props to xxx.vue file

Tags: vue.js, vuejs2, vue-component

Normally you send props like this way

```
Vue.component('child', {
  // camelCase in JavaScript
  props: ['myMessage'],
  template: '<span>{{ myMessage }}</span>'
})
```

How can i achieve with require:

```
Vue.component('lw-login', require('./components/login.vue'));
```

Laravel Blade Template:

```
<lw-login
        heading="Login"
        action="{{ route('login') }}"
        email="E-mailadres"
        passwordrequest="{{ route('password.request') }}"
></lw-login>
```

login.vue:
See {{ heading }}
I am getting this error:

```
[Vue warn]: Property or method "heading" is not defined on the instance but referenced during render. Make sure to declare reactive data properties in the data option.
```

(found in  at C:\Code\cms\resources\assets\js\components\login.vue)

```
<template>
    <div class="container">
        <div class="row">
            <div class="col-md-12">
                <div class="panel panel-default">
                    <div class="panel-heading">{{ heading }}</div>
                    <div class="panel-body">
                        <form class="form-horizontal" role="form" method="POST" :action="action">


                            etc .....

<script>
    export default {
        mounted() {
            props: ['heading','action','passwordrequest']
        }
    }
</script>
```

Comment: doesn't the `./components/login.vue` contain a vue component which could have the props?

Comment: I'm sending them via template, added to my question.

Comment: your template already contains `lw-login`? shouldn't it be some other tag?

Comment: I have added more code. Hope that you can help me :))

Comment: There is a syntax error in your code, I am not sure why you didnt get this error but you have `props: ['heading','action','passwordrequest']` inside mounted.

Comment: My fault :(( Thanks!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Changed this:

```
<script>
    export default {
        mounted() {
            props: ['heading','action','passwordrequest'],
        }
    }
</script>
```

To this :)) :

```
<script>
    export default {
        props: ['heading','action','passwordrequest'],
        mounted() {

        }
    }
</script>
```